# <> on mysql password

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I've refer all the related links regarding Special character on MySQL password. but I'm unable to find answer for this

my database credential is

```
User Name : root
Password  : <F8>T\]brr
```

When I logged through PhpMyAdmin it works fine. But in **php it's recognized as a tag element** (Please check the image, So you're able to understand)

```
'password' => '<F8>T\]brr',
```

[image]

[image: Error]

something missing on this ? please help

---

**EDIT 01**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '<F8>T\\]brr',
    'database' => 'cooperative',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Thats just your editors highlighting. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: no i'm getting error unable to connect

Comment: try escaping \ character

Comment: Why do you think that connection error is because of your password? Can you include your connection PHP code? I think it's because of something else.

Comment: @Don'tPanic added. please check sir

Comment: Sorry, I meant the code that actually establishes the connection, not just the connection  parameters. Are you using some framework, or just plain PHP?

Comment: As a note, it looks like CodeIgniter. Is that correct?

Comment: codeigniter framework

Comment: Ah, never mind about including that connection code then. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `<` `>` that's failing...

It's the  `\`

Needs to be escaped .. IE: `'password' => '<F8>T\\]brr',`